# Mysql database tables empty after export

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

I just finished designing a wordpress site. However, when i export the database and import it on the live server, the tables come up empty making my site not display properly.

I tried creating a new database on the localhost and importing the .sql file there, same issue.

Anyone know why this is happening? please help!!

Comment: check your exported database file. It may not exporded data conleatly. Try with new exported database. also check your local and live servers mysal versions,

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your export file?

Answer (score 1):

Use [migrate db plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)

you can export the database from the WordPress admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps:

1. Export data base with Custom - display all possible options
2. Select all the table row. Then Export the sql file.

I hope This will help you a lot.

[image: Click Here to view]

Comment: thanks, i did it like this, creates all the tables but all empty. i will try doing it via the wp admin using the migrate db plugin, hope that works. thanks again